# Scraping each element from each row from an HTML table

Tags: python, selenium

Link to website: http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player-classic.cgi?p=RafaelNadal

I am trying to write code which goes through each row in a table and extracts each element from that row.
I am aiming for an ouput in the following layout

```
Row1Element1, Row1Element2, Row1Element3 
Row2Element1, Row2Element2, Row2Element3
Row3Element1, Row3Element2, Row3Element3
```

I have had two major attempts at coding this.

Attempt 1:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table//body//tr')
elements = rows.find_elements_by_xpath('//td')
#this gets all rows in the table, but then gets all elements on the page, 
not just the table
```

Attempt 2:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table//body//tr//td')
#this gets all the elements that I want, but makes no distinction to which 
 row each element belongs to
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site you're scraping from?

Comment: Sure, there you go

Comment: Many tables in the pages, which the table you mean?

Comment: The large one at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get table headers and use indexes to get right sequence in the row data.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player-classic.cgi?p=RafaelNadal")

table_headers = [th.text.strip() for th in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#matchheader th")]
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#matches tbody > tr")

date_index = table_headers.index("Date")
tournament_index = table_headers.index("Tournament")
score_index = table_headers.index("Score")

for row in rows:
    table_data = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    print(table_data[date_index].text, table_data[tournament_index].text, table_data[score_index].text)
```

Comment: @Michael Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted, [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

This is the locator each rows the table you mean
`XPATH: //table[@id="matches"]//tbody//tr`

First following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Each rows:

```
driver.get('http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player-classic.cgi?p=RafaelNadal')

rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="matches"]//tbody//tr')))

for row in rows:
    print(row.text)
```

Or each cells:

```
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for col in cols:
        print(col.text)
```